# Matrix multiplication issues using C++ Eigen, and matlab mexFunction

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, mex, eigen

```
    // computing the matrix operation here
    // resultEigen = Input matrix
    // result1Eigen = hidden bias 
    // result2Eigen = visible bias
    // result3Eigen = weight matrix

     MatrixXd H;
     MatrixXd V;
     double well[36];
     Map<MatrixXd>( well, H.rows(), H.cols() ) = H;        
     H = resultEigen * result3Eigen + result1Eigen;
     mexPrintf("H is here\n");
        for (int i=0; i<36; i++)
          {

             mexPrintf("%d\n",H);
          }

            mexPrintf("\n");
```

I need to build a reconstructing function for my RBM and since direct matrix multiplication could get me a better result, I have been referring to eigen  library to solve my issues but I am facing some difficulties.
when running the above code I end up getting a single value for the H matrix and I wonder why!

Moreover the parameters used in for the computation of H have been initiated as follows:

```
         double *data1 = hbias;
         Map<VectorXd>hidden_bias(data1,6,1);
         VectorXd result1Eigen;
         double result1[6];
         result1Eigen = hidden_bias.transpose();
         Map<VectorXd>(result1, result1Eigen.cols()) = result1Eigen;
         // next param
         double *data2 = vbias;
         Map<VectorXd>visible_bias(data2,6,1);
         VectorXd result2Eigen;
         double result2[6];
         result2Eigen = visible_bias.transpose();
         Map<VectorXd>(result2, result2Eigen.cols()) = result2Eigen;
         // next param
         double *data3 = w;
         Map<MatrixXd>weight_matrix(data3,n_visible,n_hidden);
         MatrixXd result3Eigen;
         // double result3[36];

         mxArray * result3Matrix = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n_visible, n_hidden, mxREAL );
         double *result3=(double*)mxGetData(result3Matrix);
         result3Eigen = weight_matrix.transpose();
         Map<MatrixXd>(result3, result3Eigen.rows(), result3Eigen.cols()) = result3Eigen
```

At last I also face issues printing out data using std::cout from inside the mexFunction.
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The cout issue have been up before,  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/5990 I assume you run this on windows?

Comment: yes Patrik , I am running it on Windows, i will have a look at the link you just shared as well. thanks

Comment: Further, looking at your code it seems a bit weird. I have not used eigen, but there are some things that come into mind. For example, what is the size of `H`? What does `H.rows()` and `H.cols()` return? In case I would write a default constructor to initialize a matrix I would initialize the matrix as an empty matrix of size [0,0]. Then I would have a number of overloaded constructors initializing a matrix with size [N,M]. A quick look at eigen gives the impression that this is what happens. Try to initialize your matrix as a 6-by-6 matrix or something and try to find a tutorial on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the printing code which should be:

```
mexPrintf("%d\n",H(i));
```

Then, there is no need to duplicate vectors and matrices. For instance, `result1` is useless, as you can get a raw pointer to the data stored in `result1Eigen` using `result1Eigen.data()`. Likewise, you can directly assign `weight_matrix.transpose()` to `Map<MatrixXd>(result3,...)`, and I don't see the purpose of `well`.

Finally, if sizes are really known at compile-time, then better using `Matrix<double,6,1>` instead of a `VectorXd` and `Matrix<double,6,6>` instead of a `MatrixXd`. Yo ucan expect significant speedup.

Comment: Lovely Ggael, it does the job and i still don't believe i manage to miss the iteration over all the (i) elements while printing H. It works and you are also right with the mapping in case size would be known. But i would size of those matrices to be assigned dynamically. Thank you very much for the hints. really appreciate.